# Modified time after copying a file

Tags: file, perl

In perl 5, Using stat on a file that was freshly copied from an old file, it seems that mtime is the time in which the old file was initially created, not copied.

How do I get the copy time? ctime seems the closest, however there are warnings in the documentation about compatibility across OSs.

Comment: I'm sorry, but none of the replies I got (including yours) were clear enough for me to use. Behaviors are different across OSs, documentation is unclear - seems like each OS has its own, un-coherent definition of the 3 timestamps. Also see my last comment on the bottom reply.

Comment: Alright then. Thanks for replying. That's just what it is with timestamps.  If you really need a portable way to track your copy time you'd have to write far more code than call a flag/builtin.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: you can't in most cases.

`ctime` is **not** the file creation time. Quoting from `man 7 inode` on a Linux system:

> Last status change timestamp (`ctime`)
>                 `stat.st_ctime`; `statx.stx_ctime`
>
> This is the file's last status change timestamp.  It is  changed
>   by  writing or by setting inode information (i.e., owner, group,
>   link count, mode, etc.).

Unless

- you don't require portability
- are running on kernel with support for it
- the file is on a file system that has support for it.

Quoting from `man 7 inode` on a Linux system:

> File creation (birth) timestamp (`btime`)
>   (not returned in the `stat` structure); `statx.stx_btime`
>
> The file's creation timestamp.  This is set on file creation and
>   not changed subsequently.
>
> The `btime` timestamp was not historically present on UNIX systems
>   and is not currently supported by most Linux filesystems.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that ctime is creation time, I was looking for a solution. Please tell me what I *can* do, not what I can't :)

Comment: I assume with "copy time" you mean "when was the copy created". That would be `btime`, which isn't portable. If you use a copy process that does not preserve file stamps, e.g. `cp --no-preserve=timestamps`, then you could use `ctime` as "file creation time".

Comment: The mtime of a new file just copied from an old file will be the time of the copy, unless whatever tool used to copy sets times; e.g.$ perl -le'print scalar localtime( (stat "/etc/passwd")[9])'
Tue Dec 11 20:33:24 2018
$ cp /etc/passwd /tmp
$ perl -le'print scalar localtime( (stat "/tmp/passwd")[9])'
Mon Jan 28 13:07:29 2019

Comment: Just tried: in Windows File Explorer, created a file, made a copy of it, ran:


my @statA = stat "C:\\tempcopy.txt";
print "$statA[8]\n";
print "$statA[9]\n";


And got:


1548699422
1539269413

Answer (score 1):

There are a few unspecified details, but it seems that `ctime` timestamp is the best builtin tool at your disposal. (For Windows, also see the module linked below.)

On Windows, according to [perlport (Files and Filesystems)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Files-and-Filesystems), the *inode change time* time-stamp

> ... may really be the "creation timestamp" (which it is not in Unix).

This would directly work for you, if the file is created by copying.

In Unix `ctime` does track the inode change (along with metadata changes), what seems to be what you need. This timestamp can also be obtained simply with the `-C` [file-test operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

If the copying may update the contents of an existing file I don't see why `ctime` wouldn't work.

Note the module [Win32API::File::Time](http://search.cpan.org/~wyant/Win32API-File-Time-0.006/lib/Win32API/File/Time.pm), with the purpose to

> provide maximal access to the file creation, modification, and access times under MSWin32

Please see some caveats in docs. I haven't used it and can't test on Windows now.